# How to dequeue the right custom cell in a UITableView based on data pulled from database?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with two custom `UITableViewCell` classes that I deque and display in the table view.

My storyboard looks like so:

[image]

Previously, I was hard-coding in the data and based on the `UITableView`'s `indexPath.row`, I would dequeue the appropriate custom cell class and load the data.

An example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0...9:

            let 3Pic = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "3PicRow", for: indexPath) as! 3PicRowCell

            if indexPath.row == 0
            {
                3Pic.leftNameLabel.text = "Name"
                3Pic.leftPositionLabel.text = "Position"
                3Pic.leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")

                3Pic.MidddleNameLabel.text = "Name"
                3Pic.MiddlePositionLabel.text = "Position"
                3Pic.MiddleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")

                3Pic.RightNameLabel.text = "Name"
                3Pic.RightPositionLabel.text = "Position"
                3Pic.RightImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 1 // row=1 through row=9
            {
                // Do same thing
            }
            return 3Pic

        case 10...12:
            let 2Pic = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "2PicRow", for: indexPath) as! 2PicRowCell

            if indexPath.row == 10
            {
                2Pic.leftNameLabel.text = "Name"
                2Pic.leftPositionLabel.text = "Position"
                2Pic.leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_about")

                2Pic.rightNameLabel.text = "Name"
                2Pic.rightPositionLabel.text = "Position"
                2Pic.rightImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")
            }

            // Do same thing until row=12

            return 2Pic
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Will never reach here
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Now that we are migrating to strictly data being fetched from a database, I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how I can dequeue the appropriate cell based on the amount of data being fetched.

JSON data example:

```
{
    "item1": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "First",
        "last_name": "Last",
        "position": "Position",
        "image_url": "icon.com"
    },
    "item2": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "First",
        "last_name": "Last",
        "position": "Position",
        "image_url": "icon.com"
    },
    "item3": {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "First",
        "last_name": "Last",
        "position": "Position",
        "image_url": "icon.com"
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide a solution for my dilemma?

Comment: Your data source needs to indicate what type of cell is to be dequeued if you are doing this dynamically. Look at the data for that particular section and row and then choose a `3pic` or a `2pic`.

Comment: @RoboticCat: I feel like I understand what you're saying, but can you provide an example so I can understand better?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  is your example the data for a single row or the entire data for the table?

Comment: @Paulw11: the JSON data is for the entire table. For example if there are a total of 6 items, I'd like to only dequeue `3Pic`, bit if if the data contains 7 items, I'd like to somehow dequeue `3Pic` for loading the first 6 items, then dequeue `2Pic` for the remaining 7th item.

Comment: You may be better off using a collection view than a tableview, but you will need to calculate the integer division of your count by 3 and if there is a remainder. This tells you the number of rows. Then when returning a cell work out if the row is < count/3 or if you are in the last row

Answer (score 0):

You can check the key count of a `row` of JSON data. If you have 3 keys, use the `3pic` cell. If you have 2 keys use the `2pic` cell.

Pseudocode would look a bit like the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let jsonObject = jsonData[indexPath.row]
    let keyCount = jsonObject.keys.count

    if keyCount == 3 {
        3Pic.leftNameLabel.text = "Name"
        3Pic.leftPositionLabel.text = "Position"
        3Pic.leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")

        3Pic.MidddleNameLabel.text = "Name"
        3Pic.MiddlePositionLabel.text = "Position"
        3Pic.MiddleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")

        3Pic.RightNameLabel.text = "Name"
        3Pic.RightPositionLabel.text = "Position"
        3Pic.RightImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")
    } else {
        2Pic.leftNameLabel.text = "Name"
        2Pic.leftPositionLabel.text = "Position"
        2Pic.leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_about")

        2Pic.rightNameLabel.text = "Name"
        2Pic.rightPositionLabel.text = "Position"
        2Pic.rightImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")
    }

    return cell
}
```

I do think using a collection view would be a cleaner approach. You would just need only 1 cell.

Comment: I use a collection view elsewhere in my code, but the reason I wanted to use a table view in this situation is because if there are 2 items left to be filled and I have a collection view of 3 cells per row, I didn't the 3rd row to be "empty", which is why I have the 2 items aligned to make it look "cleaner"

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a second tableview cell for this.  You should use UIStackView.  Each image and label is a vertical stack view and all three and in a horizontal stackview.  Simply hide the middle vertical stackview when you have no info to show for it and the horizontal stackview will redistribute the other 2 stackviews to take its place.